# storing sum() results in database vs calculating during runtime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I'm new to sql & php and unsure about how to proceed in this situation:

I created a mysql database with two tables. 
One is just a list of users with their data, each having a unique id. 
The second one awards certain amounts of points to users, with relevant columns being the user id and the amount of awarded points. This table is supposed to get new entries regularly and there's no limit to how many times a single user can appear in it.

On my php page I now want to display a list of users sorted by their point total.

My first approach was creating a "points_total" column in the user table, intending to run some kind of query that would calculate and update the correct total for each user every time new entries are added to the other table. To retrieve the data I could then use a very simple query and even use sql's sort features.

However, while it's easy to update the total for a specific user with the sum where function, I don't see a way to do that for the whole user table. After all, plain sql doesn't offer the ability to iterate over each row of a table, or am I missing a different way?
I could probably do the update by going over the table in php, but then again, I'm not sure if that is even a good approach in the first place, because in a way storing the point data twice (the total in one table and then the point breakdown with some additional information in a different table) seems redundant.

A different option would be forgoing the extra column, and instead calculating the sums everytime the php page is accessed, then doing the sorting stuff with php. However, I suppose this would be much slower than having the data ready in the database, which could be a problem if the tables have a lot of entries?

I'm a bit lost here so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can certainly do this with SQL. The decisive factor would probably be the volume of the data being queried.

Comment: As this will be a cumulative column, is it possible for a row with an earlier date to be inserted? If so, calculate at runtime, or look at data warehousing

Comment: Rather than storing and maintaining a total field in the user, you can construct a simple SQL query that provides the totals. Unless you expect an extreme number of records, this method may work for you. If you expect a lot of records, ie. millions, then setting up triggers (insert and update) on the points table to update the user record would work. The complication comes if a points record is updated. You would need to subtract the points in the original record and add the points in the new record.

Comment: @mkaatman This is a `database-design` question, and as such it will certainly have some subjectivity. If the `database-design` flag is allowed in SO, then such questions should also be allowed.

Comment: @mkaatman, I agree with Giorgos Altanis. There is some subjectivity, but it is a question about two possible methodologies and how each might be implemented.

Comment: I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @mkaatman opinion based would be a poor fit over there just as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See  **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat is his question (db design) not part of the planning stage in the software development life cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the total points awarded, you could use a query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    `user_name`,
    `user_id`,
    SUM(`points`.`points_award`) as `points`,
    COUNT(`points`.`points_award`) as `numberOfAwards`
FROM `users`
JOIN `points`
    ON `users`.`user_id` = `points`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `users`.`user_name` // or whatever users column you want.
```

Comment: this however only gives me the point total for the user with the id 1, right? is it possible to get the totals for each user with a single sql query?

Comment: @rs11 Just ignore the `WHERE` clause

Comment: thanks, yea should have known about the group by statement :D this should basically solve my problem

Comment: Glad it helped.